# MikroTik and c# API: get radio-name with ':put' command

Tags: c#, api, networking, network-programming, mikrotik

I have an issue. I want to get radio-name through the C# api for winbox. In winboxs terminal works `:put [/interface wireless get [/interface wireless find default-name=wlan1] radio-name]` command, but not in C# api. I rode that, in api i can't uses [ ] marks, but i dont know how it write without it. I tried like this:

```
mikrotik.Send("/put ", true);
mikrotik.Send(".system identity get name", true);
foreach (string h in mikrotik.Read())
    {
         mkResult += h;
    }

l_identify.Text = mkResult;
```

but its doesn't work. Everytime i get this:

!trap=category=0=message=no such command or directiory (put [)!trap=message=no such command prefix!done

Please help :<

PS: Sorry for my English :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending incorrect commands to the device.

You need to use this:

```
/interface/wireless/print
=.proplist=radio-name
?default-name=wlan1
```

`.proplist` contains list of fields to be returned, `?default-name=wlan1` is a condifion for filtering.

You can find more about Mikrotik API syntax in the [official Wiki](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:API).